# How to run one NUnit test under a user with certain privileges

Tags: c#, permissions, nunit, integration-testing, privileges

Is it possible to run one of the tests in a testsuite under a specific user account? I need to simulate somehow a user privileges issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
runas.exe /user:DOMAIN\someUser "nunit-console.exe somelibrary.dll"
```

Comment: yep. i know how to run all the tests under the specific user. but what about the one in the dll

Comment: @Leonid, I don't think you could run a single test under a different account. You could externalize this specific test into a separate assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I've consolidated the key points into one answer and provided an outline of the steps involved.

I've also added information on using new NUnit 3 "NUnit-Lite" single-exe tests+runner, and using the Windows Task Scheduler as a simple mechanism to run the test(s) under the user account.

Darin Dimitrov's answer is on the money overall, but a couple of excellent points are buried in comments, and some people might want more guidance on how to set this up.  Plus NUnit-Lite was not available when he wrote his answer.

Part 1: Place the test(s) that need to be run under the specific user account into their own separate assembly.  Approximate steps:

- For example, in Visual Studio you would select File/New Project, and select the NUnit project template (in Framework or .NET Core, as appropriate), name the project appropriately.
- Move the code for the specific tests involved into the new assembly you just created.  Get the assembly to build and run, and to give expected results with the account you are logged in under in Visual Studio.  Don't worry about other user accounts just yet.
- Option: Use the NUnit-Lite single EXE test runner packaging approach, new in NUnit3, as documented here: https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/NUnitLite-Runner.html

Part 2: Deploy the test assembly to the location where you will be running it, in order to be able to use the nunit-console.exe program to run the tests in the assembly.

- See NUnit documentation for runtime requirements.

Part 3: Set up to execute nunit-console or your NUnit-Lite single EXE under the specific user account.

- Option 1: use "runas" approach
  runas.exe /user:DOMAIN\someUser "nunit-console.exe somelibrary.dll"
  OR
  runas.exe /user:DOMAIN\someUser "MyTestsAndNUnitLiteRunner.exe"
- I believe you would start up a Command Prompt; in Windows 10 it would be Start/(type CMD) and then you would right-click on the "Command Prompt" choice, and select "Run as different user", and then enter the userID and credentials for the specific user.
- In some versions of Windows 10, you won't see the "Run as different user" option.  If that happens, refer to this article: https://superuser.com/questions/1045158/how-do-you-run-as-a-different-user-from-the-start-menu-in-windows-10
- Option 2: use Windows Task scheduler to set up a job that runs under the desired user account.  You will need the user account login and credentials during the task setup process.  Once the scheduled task is set up, you can just right-click on it and select "run" to run it immediately. The command line will be similar to this:
  "nunit-console.exe" somelibrary.dll
  OR, for NUnit-Lite:
  "MyTestsAndNUnitLiteRunner.exe"

In the task setup, you many need to use folder names and to use quotes if the paths involved have spaces in them.

Part 4: Run the test assembly, using your chosen approach, and review the output.

- See NUnit documentation for the specifics of where test output gets sent and its format.
- In my experience, NUnit wrote XML result files that I could go look at to see the test results.  The XML files are human-readable enough to view with a text editor and understand.

Part 5: Iterate until it works; adjust test code and repeat until success is achieved.

- Sometimes things work perfectly the first time, but often not.
- If you set up your Visual Studio build to deploy the updated, rebuilt test assembly to your test runner area, you can just trigger the "scheduled" task manually.

Personally, I prefer the Windows Task Scheduler approach over the runas approach.
Once it's set up, to me, it's faster and easier to iterate on the test code and retry the test.

As I mentioned, NUnit3 has a new "NUnit-Lite" runner that makes it simple to package up NUnit AND your tests into a single EXE console app.  Docs on doing that are here: https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/NUnitLite-Runner.html

Overall the NUnit-Lite single EXE approach would be my preference, over the NUnit-Console approach, in conjunction with Windows Task Scheduler.

People who are super-handy with PowerShell and batch files may prefer the RunAs approach.